# Why I can/can't redefine a typename inside a class?

Tags: c++

It is said that a `type name` cannot be defined inside a class after being used. e.g:

```
typedef double Money;
class Account {
public:
    Money balance() { return bal; } // uses Money from the outer
private:
    typedef double Money; // error: cannot redefine Money
    Money bal;
    // ...
};
```

The program doesn't work on GCC but on MSVC 14 it works fine!??
* I got this example from "C++ primer 5th edition".

Comment: I think if you kept reading a couple of lines below in your book you'll ind the answer. "Although it is an error to redefine a type name, compilers are not required to
diagnose this error. Some compilers will quietly accept such code, even though the program is in error.".

Comment: Conformance view in godbolt is quite useful for this type of question:  https://godbolt.org/z/tzYN-p